# Aggregate Functions in extbase typo3

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am using [extbase-query-method](http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/extbase-query-methods/) ( like , in ,contains ).

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->matching(
    $query->logicalAnd(
        $query->equals("deleted", "0"),
        $query->equals("hidden", "0"),
        $query->equals("status", $status)
     )
);
return $query->execute();
```

but how can i used [Aggregate Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) in extbase query statement.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Extbase doesn't support the use of aggregate functions in the ORM. See more here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

You will have to build the SQL query yourself (in the statement) and to tell the query to return raw result (that is stored in an array) instead of returning an object based query.

Exemple:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->statement("SELECT AVG(clicks) as 'avg' FROM tablename ...");
$query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);
$result = $query->execute()[0][avg];
```

Cheers,
Olivier

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution for Extbase Query is

```
$query->statement('SELECT AVG(clicks) FROM tablename ...')
```

Or not?

Comment: Nop,  I am looking for that methods like AVG(),MAX() and other Aggregate Functions as we already have for LIKE(),IN() etc.

Comment: These methods do not exist in Extbase:
[Query Class Reference](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_generic_1_1_query.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Plain SQL Statements, you have can get problems with sql injection!

A better way should be using the new doctrine querybuilder which is since 8.7 available:

```
// SELECT COUNT(`uid`) FROM `tt_content` WHERE (`bodytext` = 'klaus')
//     AND ((`tt_content`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`tt_content`.`hidden` = 0)
//     AND (`tt_content`.`starttime` <= 1475580240)
//     AND ((`tt_content`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`tt_content`.`endtime` > 1475580240)))
$count = $queryBuilder
   ->count('uid')
   ->from('tt_content')
   ->where(
      $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('bodytext', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('klaus'))
    )
   ->execute()
   ->fetchColumn(0);
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you cannot use these functions on the Query object itself. However, you could use the [ExpressionBuilder class](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/ExpressionBuilder/Index.html#aggregate-functions) for something like this:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('my_awesome_table');

$statement = $queryBuilder
   ->select('uid')
   ->addSelectLiteral(
      $queryBuilder->expr()->max('interesting_field', 'awesome_alias')
   )
   ->from('my_awesome_table')
   ->groupBy('interesting_field')
   ->execute();
```

Note that this returns a QueryResult object.

Answer (score -1):

The only function you can use is `COUNT()` with

```
return $query->execute()->count();
```

For all other functions you have to do a native query, like described in other answers